# Skycons/Dark Sky Forecast API, displaying animated icons for dynamically created DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, canvas, dynamic

As my first app working with an API I've decided to use the Dark Sky API.  I'm trying to add animated Skycons for each of the forecast days I generate from my JS file.  I've read the other posts on StackOverflow regarding Skycon issues but have made no progress on my own.

I've changed my initJS so that is looks for the weather type by class name, but still have been unsuccessful in appending the icons.

My script in the HTML:

```
<script>
var icons = new Skycons({"color": "#fff"}),
      list  = [
        "clear-day", "clear-night", "partly-cloudy-day",
        "partly-cloudy-night", "cloudy", "rain", "sleet", "snow", "wind",
        "fog"
      ],
      i;

  for(i = list.length; i--; ) {
var weatherType = list[i],
    elements = document.getElementsByClassName( weatherType );
for (e = elements.length; e--;){
    icons.set( elements[e], weatherType );
}
}

  icons.play();
```

How I create the forecast divs that hold the icons:

```
//HTML to append to document
      var html =
        '<div class="forecast-list"><ul class="list">' +
        '<li class="item" id="day">' + forecastDay + '</li>' +
                          //The canvas tag is where the SKYCON should show up
        '<li class="item"><canvas class="' + forecastIcon + '" width="128" height="128"></canvas></li>' +
        '<li class="item forecastTemp" id="max">' + forecastMax + '</li>' +
        '<li class="item forecastTemp" id="min">' + forecastMin + '</li>' +
        '</ul></div><br><br>';

      //Append HTML to document
      $('.forecast').append(html);
```

A link to my codepen: http://codepen.io/DDD37/pen/GozGGx

A link to Skycons for refrence: https://github.com/darkskyapp/skycons/blob/master/skycons.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found where I went wrong.  I was creating the icons in the wrong spot.  This code...

```
var icons = new Skycons({"color": "#111"}),
      list  = [
        "clear-day", "clear-night", "partly-cloudy-day",
        "partly-cloudy-night", "cloudy", "rain", "sleet", "snow", "wind",
        "fog"
      ],
      i;

  for(i = list.length; i--; ) {
var weatherType = list[i],
    elements = document.getElementsByClassName( weatherType );
      console.log(elements);
for (e = elements.length; e--;){
    icons.set( elements[e], weatherType );
}
}

  icons.play();
```

...needed to be placed inside the AJAX call.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for posting this solution. Worked like a charm Cheers!